# Typescript - Unexpected error when using includes with a typed array

Tags: typescript

With the following code we produce two arrays:

```
const PROVIDERS: {
  PROVIDER_1: 'PROVIDER_1';
  PROVIDER_2: 'PROVIDER_2';
  PROVIDER_3: 'PROVIDER_3';
} = {
  PROVIDER_1: 'PROVIDER_1',
  PROVIDER_2: 'PROVIDER_2',
  PROVIDER_3: 'PROVIDER_3',
};

const GOOD_PROVIDERS = [PROVIDERS.PROVIDER_1, PROVIDERS.PROVIDER_2];
const BAD_PROVIDERS = [PROVIDERS.PROVIDER_3];
```

The types are:

```
const GOOD_PROVIDERS: ("PROVIDER_1" | "PROVIDER_2")[]
const BAD_PROVIDERS: ("PROVIDER_3")[]
```

Then, if I try to check if a value is included in one of those arrays I face several compilation errors that I don't know how to handle:

```
const provider: 'PROVIDER_1' | 'PROVIDER_2' | 'PROVIDER_3' = getProvider();
const isGood = GOOD_PROVIDERS.includes(provider);
const isBad = BAD_PROVIDERS.includes(provider);
```

The includes of GOOD_PROVIDERS throws this error

> Argument of type '"PROVIDER_1" | "PROVIDER_2" | "PROVIDER_3"' is not
> assignable to parameter of type '"PROVIDER_1" | "PROVIDER_2"'.   Type
> '"PROVIDER_3"' is not assignable to type '"PROVIDER_1" |
> "PROVIDER_2"'.ts(2345)

The includes of BAD_PROVIDERS throws this error

> Argument of type '"PROVIDER_1" | "PROVIDER_2" | "PROVIDER_3"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"PROVIDER_3"'.
> Type '"PROVIDER_1"' is not assignable to type '"PROVIDER_3"'.ts(2345)

Why does Array.includes assume that the argument is already in the list? Is there any other way to check this?

Comment: I found this explanation about the type definition https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255

Answer (score 22):

I changed for `some()` method:

```js
array.some((arr) => arr === otherParameter)
```

In your case would be:

```js
const isGood = GOOD_PROVIDERS.some((GOOD_PROVIDER) => GOOD_PROVIDER === provider);
```

Answer (score 7):

> Why does Array.includes assume that the argument is already in the list?

[The link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255) in your comment already kind of answers that. The TL;DR is that adding typings to an array is similar to creating an abstract set of values, and going beyond this set is chosen to be a compiler error. Some might like it, some might hate it, but it is what it is (at least, for now).

> Is there any other way to check this?

Yes.

Starting with TypeScript 1.6 you can use [`(x) => x is Type` type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#user-defined-type-guard-functions). I find this feature (along with [`(x) => asserts x is Type` assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)) very convenient to work with, extremely useful, and kind of like magic to be honest:

<sub>*In the following example, I'm going to assume that you don't have control over the definition of the `PROVIDERS` object. If you do, go to the next example.*</sub>

```
const PROVIDERS: {
  PROVIDER_1: 'PROVIDER_1';
  PROVIDER_2: 'PROVIDER_2';
  PROVIDER_3: 'PROVIDER_3';
} = {
  PROVIDER_1: 'PROVIDER_1',
  PROVIDER_2: 'PROVIDER_2',
  PROVIDER_3: 'PROVIDER_3',
};

type GoodProvider = typeof PROVIDERS.PROVIDER_1 | typeof PROVIDERS.PROVIDER_2;
type BadProvider = typeof PROVIDERS.PROVIDER_3;
type Provider = GoodProvider | BadProvider;

// Notice that types here are broadened, – otherwie this won't work
// The distinction between good vs bad providers has been moved to typings instead
const GOOD_PROVIDERS: Provider[] = [PROVIDERS.PROVIDER_1, PROVIDERS.PROVIDER_2];
const BAD_PROVIDERS: Provider[] = [PROVIDERS.PROVIDER_3];

function isGoodProvider(provider: Provider): provider is GoodProvider {
  return GOOD_PROVIDERS.includes(provider);
}

// You might not need both functions though; but if you do, here's the second one
function isBadProvider(provider: Provider): provider is BadProvider {
  return BAD_PROVIDERS.includes(provider);
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/w8AePN).*

If you're in control of the `PROVIDERS` object, you're in luck, because you can do some major optimizations, – both textual (less code to write) and logical (no logic duplication).

Using `as const`, you can define source-of-truth objects, and infer all the necessary typings from them, – this is the approach I use all over, and it is great in its robustness:

```
const GOOD_PROVIDERS = {
  PROVIDER_1: 'PROVIDER_1',
  PROVIDER_2: 'PROVIDER_2',
} as const;

const BAD_PROVIDERS = {
  PROVIDER_3: 'PROVIDER_3',
} as const;

type GoodProvider = keyof typeof GOOD_PROVIDERS;
type BadProvider = keyof typeof BAD_PROVIDERS;
type Provider = GoodProvider | BadProvider;

function isGoodProvider(provider: Provider): provider is GoodProvider {
  return provider in GOOD_PROVIDERS;
}

function isBadProvider(provider: Provider): provider is BadProvider {
  return provider in BAD_PROVIDERS;
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/WPjYEN).*