# How to resolve "Type is not assignable to type" in TypeScript if statement?

Tags: typescript

I have 2 sets of keys: `KEY_SET_1` and `KEY_SET_2`. `KEY_SET_1` has keys `A` to `D` while `KEY_SET_2` has keys `E` to `H`. I have a function that needs to handle key in both key sets differently. However, I run into an error that says

> Argument of type 'AllKeySetType' is not assignable to parameter of type '"A" | "B" | "C" | "D"'. Type '"E"' is not assignable to type '"A" | "B" | "C" | "D"'.".

I wonder what is the best way to go about it in TypeScript in this case? Thanks.

[Link to TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gUQJoH0DKCAqKCMMC8MA2gOQCCJANDCQEJU0DCDJAIiQLowCGEMokKAG4AUAOjxk6LCgBMBYiQQsAYiwDiLABKcefccJEioATwAOAU3gWTaC1ByZzVwgApTlkADNJqDNhwASiIwAFcAWwAjCwAnDlEPKzgbOyhZJ0sFd2dvX2lsWWCwqNj442cYMgAbKuTbewyXa3qHRpgAH2bU9OdRMXAJAAtuMAATKos6rIBrGwAuSpq61MbAggA%20GABvERgYAEsfV0Q-GRwAOn2wYCrQ0YsIV1mTQMCdvb2Aek%20YLRHxqzPGAQewwHC7GAAXwsVRB7w%2031%20-wmMCBINgsghkJEkKAA)

```js
const KEY_SET_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] as const;
const KEY_SET_2 = ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'] as const;

type KeySet1Type = (typeof KEY_SET_1)[number];
type KeySet2Type = (typeof KEY_SET_2)[number];
type AllKeySetType = KeySet1Type | KeySet2Type;

const handleKey = (key: AllKeySetType) => {
  if (KEY_SET_1.includes(key)){ // <- Error here
    // Handle key set 1
  }else{
    // Handle key set 2
  }
}
```

I can make the error disappears by casting `key as KeySet1Type` but I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can make the error disappears by casting key as KeySet1Type
> but I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Indeed, it's rather the type of `KEY_SET_1` that is the problem there and should be cast to `readonly string[]`.  But I suppose you'd want an actual type guard there, so that the type of `key` is strictly known to the compiler after the test, so here is how I'd rewrite it:

```
const KEY_SET_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] as const;
const KEY_SET_2 = ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'] as const;

type KeySet1Type = (typeof KEY_SET_1)[number];
type KeySet2Type = (typeof KEY_SET_2)[number];
type AllKeySetType = KeySet1Type | KeySet2Type;

function isOfKeySet<KS extends AllKeySetType>(ks: readonly KS[], key: string): key is KS {
  return (ks as readonly string[]).includes(key);
}

const handleKey = (key: AllKeySetType) => {
  if (isOfKeySet(KEY_SET_1, key)) {
    key;  // (parameter) key: "A" | "B" | "C" | "D"
  } else {
    key;  // (parameter) key: "E" | "F" | "G" | "H"
  }
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gUQJoH0DKCAqKCMMC8MA2gOQCCJANDCQEJU0DCDJAIiQLowCGEMokKAG4AUAOjxk6LCgBMBYiQQsAYiwDiLABKcefccJEioATwAOAU3gWTaC1ByZzVwgApTlkADNJqDNhwASiIwAFcAWwAjCwAnDlEPKzgbOyhZJ0sFd2dvX2lsWWCwqNj442cYMgAbKuTbewyXa3qHRpgAH2bU9OdRES9QsGAoAEtwGBGIAHkvOtSAHjg0GAsADygLMAATPmralIbnAD5XAGsIAC4YGItuLfAqk3g0Ig5qU5sr6BiRsABzQJXD5PSbPGAAbxEMGu9lCMTAMDOfF4MLuDye31%20f1egQAdL9gFVQlsLBAzjZAqIAL5GAwwAAW3G2VQsdSywKuezmh0sgQIRwhUImPlckxm3KgrkQfhkOHeFL5kOh0OBQmhAHp1YizNwYtxwvZYnyOTAAERkU0dM20S2dU2MW1m1imoVUlZVCBWJXK1UarWuHV6g0bGLGz5mhCO00qKPqKNaF3Qmk0oA)

Comment: Very cool and helpful generic solution, thanks for sharing

Comment: Glad it helps, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just took a closer look, it seems the issue is partly on `includes` and partly on TypeScript not being smart enough on array. I was able to find an answer at [Typescript - Unexpected error when using includes with a typed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906553/typescript-unexpected-error-when-using-includes-with-a-typed-array) and resolved it with `some` and type guard.

```js
const isKeySet1 = (key: AllKeySetType): key is KeySet1Type => {
    return KEY_SET_1.some((keySet1Key) => keySet1Key === key);
};
```